# Sequelize query where record does not exist in related table or does exist in related table with condition

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write a sequelize query which includes a relation from different table with hasMany relation. I want my query to return if some column in related table has matches my condition or there is not related row in the related table with foreign key from my main table.

Think about two different models, main one, which is folders, has id, name etc. columns and related table, which is folderOwners has id, folderId and groupId columns which shows which folders is owned by which groups. So, folders can have multiple owner groups.

```
include: [{
          association: "owners",
          required: true,
          where: {
            groupId: {[Op.in]: userGroups.map(group => group.id)}
          }
        }]
```

I can get the folders which owned by one of the groups that user is in but I want to get all folders if there is no row in related table, which means folder is not owned by anyone. 
I've tried to change required to false and use Op.or for where like below

```
         required: true,
          where: {
          [Op.or]: [
            {groupId: {[Op.in]: userGroups.map(group => group.id)}},
            {groupId: {[Op.eq]: null}}
              ],
          }
```

So, are there any ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: Well, I ended up using Sequelize.Literal to execute SQL Query inside where clause which consists IN and NOT EXISTS with parameters and deleting include for owners association since I don't actually need it in the result. If there is a way to do it with include, it will be good to know.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly your problem, try this code :

```
    Folder.findAll({include: [{model: Group, required: false}])
```

it will get all the folders with and without Groups

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but actually what I want to achive is not that. I wanted to get results if column is null or matches the condition I queried. Assume that I wanted to get rows that has 3 or null in given column. If column has 3,4,5 as an array or null, query should return that row but not if it only has 4,5 as an array. I ended up using sequelize literal and standart sql.

Comment: You can do that with the where statement :

        const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
        const Op = Sequelize.Op;
        Folder.findAll({include: [{model: Group, required: false, where : { _col: {  [Op.or]: [{ [Op.in]: [3] }, { [Op.is]: null }  }  }  }])

Comment: Hi, long time passed over the question and I forgot some details. Sorry about that. I also wanted if there is no row matched with the related folder. So if there is no row for include statement, I mean with the related id, I also want this row in the main table to be returned. It was complicated back then, got more complicated after I forgot details. I had to read my question again, but it has to be queried with EXISTS I believe.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference to nested model's column from parent model's "where" object using syntax like this: "$AssociatedTableName.columnName$"

```
Folder.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { '$Group.id$': null },
      {
        '$Group.id$': {
          [Op.in]: [ids],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: Group,
      as: 'Group',
      required: false,
    },
  ],
});
```